# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error for a binary compiled in WSL environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, compatibility, elf

I have recently started working on WSL environment.
I have compiled one program in WSL environment which is of type "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object" but when I try to run it in the same environment, it throws an error "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

I am not sure about what I am missing here. How can I run the binary.
Kindly suggest.

```
kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~/runtime/bin$ ioc_broker &
[1] 3579
kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~/runtime/bin$ bash: /bin/ioc_broker: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
^C
[1]+  Exit 126                ioc_broker
kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~/runtime/bin$ file ioc_broker 
ioc_broker: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=aa1e76d798d46d45f131cb53de8f947ddb4c8526, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~/runtime/bin$ uname -srv
Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022
kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~/runtime/bin$ 

kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:/mnt/d/src/myproject/build$ uname -a
Linux APL-5CD010D2WP 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have compiled the binary using cmake in which I have specified nothing specific about comiler being used.

```
kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:/mnt/d/src/myproject/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/kshitij/runtime ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Line: 57 Using COMMON_API_VERSION 3.1.12
```

Comment: What does `file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` say?

Comment: And how did you compile your program?

Comment: kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~$ file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: symbolic link to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so  
  

kshitij@APL-5CD010D2WP:~$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4587364908de169dec62ffa538170118c1c3a078, stripped

Comment: Might be related to one regression after a Windows Update.
See: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `uname -srv`
> `Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022`

Try `uname -a` instead. It should identify the kernel as either `i686` or `x86_64`.

I expect that your kernel says `i686`, in which case you've installed a 32-bit WSL2 and are trying to run a 64-bit binary on it. That doesn't work for obvious reason -- you need a 64-bit kernel to run 64-bit binaries.

**Update:**

> I see x86_64

Ok, my guess was wrong. The other reason for `Exec format error` is that the file is corrupt in some way.

One possible source of corruption is if you run out of disk space and the file is truncated. Check `df -h .` output and if there is a lot of space, try rebuilding the binary again.

Also try `eu-readelf -a ioc_broker` -- `eu-readelf` is good at warning about corrupt ELF files.

Finally, look in `/var/log/messages` for any kernel warnings -- you may have a bad disk block or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see x86_64 being listed there. I have updated the same in question description section.

Comment: @Kshitij_9192 I've updated the answer with some other things to try.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. With help of eu-readelf , I found that file was indeed curropted. I performed a clean build from scratch and then I was able to run it.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for the problem is:

```bash
wsl$ sudo apt install binfmt-support
wsl$ sudo sh -c 'echo :WSLInterop:M::MZ::/init:PF > /usr/lib/binfmt.d/WSLInterop.conf'
wsl$ exit
powershell> wsl --shutdown
```

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8986#issuecomment-1662906004)

Comment: Works but we shouldn't need that.
There was a regression after a Windows Update.
See: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10363